# How to get response from Array in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

Here is my response. I don't know how to create Response Model for this type of response model

```
[{"id":"4","templateName":"FUP 100","dataUsage":"100 GB","price":236,"groupName":"","bandwidthName":""},{"id":"19","templateName":"FUP200","dataUsage":"200 GB","price":299.72,"groupName":"","bandwidthName":""}]
```

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. Use this site. It will create response models from your response string.

Comment: I don't know what document you are following but i think its mentioned  in each and every doc. Try some reading .

Answer (score 2):

your retrofit call must be a list of your object not just the object

your object is like that

```
public class MyClass
{
    private String id;

    private String groupName;

    private String price;

    private String dataUsage;

    private String bandwidthName;

    private String templateName;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGroupName ()
    {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName (String groupName)
    {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public String getPrice ()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice (String price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDataUsage ()
    {
        return dataUsage;
    }

    public void setDataUsage (String dataUsage)
    {
        this.dataUsage = dataUsage;
    }

    public String getBandwidthName ()
    {
        return bandwidthName;
    }

    public void setBandwidthName (String bandwidthName)
    {
        this.bandwidthName = bandwidthName;
    }

    public String getTemplateName ()
    {
        return templateName;
    }

    public void setTemplateName (String templateName)
    {
        this.templateName = templateName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "MyClass [id = "+id+", groupName = "+groupName+", price = "+price+", dataUsage = "+dataUsage+", bandwidthName = "+bandwidthName+", templateName = "+templateName+"]";
    }
}
```

kotlin :

```
class MyClass {
  var id:String
  var groupName:String
  var price:String
  var dataUsage:String
  var bandwidthName:String
  var templateName:String
  public override fun toString():String {
    return "MyClass [id = " + id + ", groupName = " + groupName + ", price = " + price + ", dataUsage = " + dataUsage + ", bandwidthName = " + bandwidthName + ", templateName = " + templateName + "]"
  }
}
```

there are online tools to help you http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: Thank you @gmetax

Comment: @kirubhasankar approve my answer as correct when it is possible

Comment: try my answer this will help you.

Comment: @kirubhasankar this problem is that you have to set your response as list not as just an object

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Response {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("templateName")
@Expose
private String templateName;
@SerializedName("dataUsage")
@Expose
private String dataUsage;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private Double price;
@SerializedName("groupName")
@Expose
private String groupName;
@SerializedName("bandwidthName")
@Expose
private String bandwidthName;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTemplateName() {
    return templateName;
}

public void setTemplateName(String templateName) {
    this.templateName = templateName;
}

public String getDataUsage() {
    return dataUsage;
}

public void setDataUsage(String dataUsage) {
    this.dataUsage = dataUsage;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public String getBandwidthName() {
    return bandwidthName;
}

public void setBandwidthName(String bandwidthName) {
    this.bandwidthName = bandwidthName;
}

}
```

Then Create ArrayList because your response start with array :

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@GET("your_api")
Call<ArrayList<Response>> api();
```

Comment: Great it worked for me..can you please give to read this reponse in retrofit @Vishal G. Gohel

Comment: do you get it how it's work ?